# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'html.parser'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

My pip3 has some problem about HTMLParser,when I want use pip to install some packages,some toubles occured.This is my log,this problem troble me a long time, and I can't resolve it,my python version is 3.7, my os version is centos 7.6.

```
    pip3 install traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/project/envs/mythril/bin/pip3", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
File "/project/envs/mythril/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 69, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
  File "/project/envs/mythril/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 91, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/project/envs/mythril/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.req_command import (
  File "/project/envs/mythril/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index.package_finder import PackageFinder
  File "/project/envs/mythril/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 32, in <module>
    from pip._internal.req import InstallRequirement
  File "/project/envs/mythril/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .req_install import InstallRequirement
  File "/project/envs/mythril/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 35, in <module>
    from pip._internal.operations.install.wheel import install_wheel
  File "/project/envs/mythril/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/install/wheel.py", line 39, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.distlib.scripts import ScriptMaker
  File "/project/envs/mythril/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .compat import sysconfig, detect_encoding, ZipFile
  File "/project/envs/mythril/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distlib/compat.py", line 85, in <module>
    from html.parser import HTMLParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'html.parser'
```

Comment: Please be more verbose. What did you try how did you fail. Everybody knows that pip has problems. What exactly is your coding problem?

Comment: I know my problem and resolve it,thank your help.